# Processing Lists of Items with ParallelFor

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver, parallel.foreach

I'm generating a report from largeish (2million+ records) data in a MongoDB instance using the C# MongoDB driver. Getting all the records and processing them serverside is slow so I've been trying different things.

The input is a List of arbitrary length what the code then has to do is query a largeish (2million record) collection for records that contain the Guids input.

INPUT                                         Dataset
{A, B, C}                                     {1-A, 2-A, 3-A, 4-C, 5-B, 6-C, 7-Z, 8-B ....   1000-Z}

A - 1-A, 2-A, 3-A = Count = 3
B - 5-B, 8-B      = Count = 2
C - 4-C, 6-C     = Count = 2

And then I need to return the set of matched records in the dataset.

The logic is sound and I've implemented it as a Linq query which runs pretty well but at just over 30s is too slow to be on the end of an API call so I'm trying to optimise it.

It seems that MongoDB is actually pretty quick at returning data so I thought I would divide up the guids into sets of x length and parallel-ise the routine:

```
   var results = new List<Instance>();
   int counter = 0; int chunksize = 50;

   Parallel.For(0, (inputs.Count() / chunksize) + 1, x =>
   {
      var cx = inputs.Skip(chunksize * counter).Take(chunksize);

      foreach (var c in cx)
      {
         checkCounter++;
         $"Processing {c}".Dump();
         var instances = _db.Get<Instance>().Where(_Predicate_);
                if (instances.Any())
                {
                    results.AddRange(instances);
                    $"Total Instances is now: {results.Count()}".Dump();
                }
            }
            
        });
```

It seems counter-intuitive (to me as a longtime SQL user) but I think its got legs. The problem is when the code runs multiple threads seem to be grabbing the same guids from the list here:

```
var cx = inputs.Skip(chunksize * counter).Take(chunksize);
```

and of course I need to ensure I'm giving each thread a unique set of guids. Can I do that in a parallel.for or should I be looking at doing something more low-level e.g. generating separate tasks?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: `results.AddRange` is not safe in `Parallel.ForEach` since `List<T>` is not thread-safe.

Comment: If it was me, I'd do `var results = inputs.Batch(chunkSize).AsParallel().Select(z => { logic here }).ToList();` `Batch` is from MoreLINQ.

Comment: What is `_Predicate_`?

Comment: Calling `instances.Any()` and then `results.AddRange(instances)` forces two calls to the DB.

Comment: @Enigmativity _Predicate_ is just a placeholder for some filter logic which would have added noise.

Comment: @indra - We love seeing the noise because it may affect our answers.

Comment: @indra - IN your case I assume that `_Predicate_` contains a reference to `c`?

Comment: `Calling instances.Any() and then results.AddRange(instances) forces two calls to the DB.` Correct. The `Any` check is completely unnecessary (since `AddRange` will handle empty fine). Remove it.

Comment: @indra Why do you want to use `Parallel.For` (which is good for CPU-bound, task based parallelism) for I/O bound operations? Why don't you use MongoDb's Async API and use `Task.WhenAll` to run your async Tasks in parallel.

Comment: Turns out Any() was just wishful thinking as it isnt supported by the Mongo driver.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `x` instead of `counter` in your loop:

```
var cx = inputs.Skip(chunksize * x).Take(chunksize);
```

Also use one of [thread-safe collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/) for `results`, or refactor your code so you generate batches and after that you process them in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
IObservable<List<Instance>> query =
    from x in Observable.Range(0, (inputs.Count() / chunksize) + 1)
    from c in inputs.Skip(chunksize * x).Take(chunksize).ToObservable()
    from i in Observable.Start(() => _db.Get<Instance>().Where(_Predicate_).ToList())
    select i;

IList<List<Instance>> data = await query.ToList();

List<Instance> results = data.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Note the use of `x` within `from c in inputs.Skip(chunksize * x).Take(chunksize).ToObservable()`. That's where your original code went wrong in using `counter`.

This code is run in parallel and will automatically build the final list without any concern about threading on `List<Instance>`.

The use of LINQ makes the code quite readable too.